# Unable to save a file as JSON?

Tags: json

Am in the need of creating a file with a extension of JSON(Json file). But I'm unable to create. When I try save a file with json extension like  file name followed by a .JSON it is  takes as,

```
  filename.JSON.txt
```

How to solve this?? Am using windows 7(32 bit) OS. Please suggest something ???

Comment: Can you post some code?  See also [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org) for tips on writing great questions.

Comment: See this document http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions#show-hide-file-name-extensions=windows-7 not sure if this is what you want, but...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you Save As..., make sure the "Save as type" dropdown contains "All Files" and not "Text Documents(*.txt)". That way it won't add the extension '.txt' but the extension you add.

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with this, but in the end it was quite simple...

In the TextEdit menu, go to "Format" and choose "Make Plain Text".
Then, save the file  and write the filename with the .json extension.  Pop-up dialogue will ask if you want to save with .json or .txt, just choose .json to confirm!

Answer (score 0):

You have to delate the extension `.txt` to get a JSON file.